# php writing to file change the string look

Tags: php, string, file-io, fopen, fwrite

I have a file named "B-small-practice.in" its content is as follow

```
this is a test
foobar
all your base
class
pony along
```

I wrote a code its function is to reverse the words in each line and write them to another file "output.txt" .
here is the code:

```
$file = fopen("B-small-practice.in", "r");
$lines = array();
while(!feof($file)){
$lines[] = fgets($file); 
}
fclose($file);

$output = fopen("output.txt", "a");

foreach($lines as $v){
    $line = explode(" ", $v);
    $reversed = array_reverse($line);
    $reversed = implode(" ", $reversed);
    fwrite($output, $reversed."\n");
}

fclose($output);
?>
```

the expected output of the code would to write to the "output.txt" the following:

```
    test a is this
    foobar
    base your all
    class
    along pony
```

But this is what I get:

```
test  
  a is this
foobar  

base  
 your all  
class

along  
 pony
```

what makes it look like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "last" part after exploding still contains the linebreak, so after revertig and imploding, the linebreak is behind the first word. just [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your string before exploding and add linebreaks (`"\n"`) again when outputting (you already do that).

Answer (score 2):

The lines already have a `\n` on them, which you are not stripping out.

Try this:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("B-small-practice.in", "r");
$lines = array();
while(!feof($file)){
$lines[] = fgets($file); 
}
fclose($file);

$output = fopen("output.txt", "a");

foreach($lines as $v){
    $v = trim($v);
    $line = explode(" ", $v);
    $reversed = array_reverse($line);
    $reversed = implode(" ", $reversed);
    fwrite($output, $reversed."\n");
}

fclose($output);
?>
```

The `trim` function should take the extra `\n` out of there.